# How to load raw heart rate vector into RHRV data structure

Tags: r, input, loading, heartrate

I am struggling with the RHRV library in R. The library is made for heart rate variability analysis and supports data files formats like ASCII, EDF, Polar, Suunto and WFDB. RHRV uses a custom data structure called HRVData to store all HRV information related to the signal being analysed. However I am working with already loaded (from .csv file) RR vectors. RRs are distances between consecutive heartbeats (in milliseconds). My exemplary data looks like:

`RR_series <- rnorm(300, mean = 1000, sd = 15)`

My problem is to insert `RR_series` into any of RHRV function so I can conduct further analysis - I want to input `RR_series` into HRVData structure.

From RHRV Quick Start Tutorial I know that "RHRV imports data files containing heart beats positions" so in worst case I can obtain time position of the heartbeat peaks - but still those will be vectors that I need to transform into HRVData somehow.

Comment: It would likely help if you `str(example_RR_vector)` as a start and paste results above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package uses a somewhat unusual mechanism for loading vectors. You need to create an empty HRVData object first using `CreateHRVData()`, then use this object as a base from which to add data. The package's functions seem designed to work best with a piped workflow.

Note that you need to supply your data as **seconds since recording started**, which means instead of passing the vector of RR intervals, you should pass the `cumsum` of the RR intervals divided by 1000:

```r
RR_series <- rnorm(300, mean = 1000, sd = 15)

RR_series <- cumsum(RR_series / 1000)
```

Getting this into the correct format is now straightforward:

```r
library(RHRV)

my_data <- CreateHRVData() |>
           LoadBeatVector(RR_series) |>
           BuildNIHR() |>
           InterpolateNIHR()
```

For example, can see a plot of instantaneous heart rate over time like this:

```
PlotHR(my_data)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>